# Vala and PolicyKit

Tags: linux, permissions, dbus, vala

I'm creating a simple GTK+ based application in Vala, which should be able to write into system directories, so it needs root access. I realize that giving full root access is a bad idea, so I need a way to gain temporary privileges.

In theory, the PolicyKit D-Bus service is the tool for the job, but I have no idea how to use it, let alone in Vala code. Any insight would be appreciated.

**update:**
I have done some further digging. My starting point was [this](https://live.gnome.org/Vala/DBusClientSamples). So basically what I need is finding out how to adapt these solutions to PolicyKit. For this, it is necessary to find the D-Bus interface of PolicyKit. I found it [here](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/0.105/eggdbus-interface-org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1.Authority.html). (Strangely I didn't find it in my local */usr/share/dbus-1/interfaces* folder.) But now I have no idea how to continue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [polkit Reference Manual](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/index.html) contains some good information, including a high-level overview on [writing polkit applications](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/polkit-apps.html).

Instead of using the D-Bus interface directly, you should probably consider using the [libpolkit-gobject-1](http://www.freedesktop.org/software/polkit/docs/latest/ref-api.html) library.  You can use the GIR directly, or generate a VAPI (which I would recommend) with vapigen.  [Here](http://pastebin.com/y471Gb8J) is one I just generated.  I'm not really familiar with the API, but it is very easy to use a C API reference as a reference to figure out the Vala API.

Comment: Actually I found out, that for my actual program this would be an overkill, but I appreciate the help. By the way I'm simply calling pkexec in an asynchronous process.

Comment: Well an update to the previous, actually _pkexec_ cannot be called asynchronously, so it is called synchronously in a background thread.