# Vala system command authentication prompt

Tags: linux, vala, password-prompt, elementary-os

so I've been working on some development for elementaryOS which uses Vala. Although it's not my preferred language i seem to be getting on okay until it comes to getting a graphical prompt for the root password.

In the terminal when i type "sudo [command]" it will prompt for the super user's password. How would i go about making a GUI version of this password prompt?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Vala and PolicyKit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15042074/vala-and-policykit)

Comment: In short: Look into PolicyKit, the easiest thing to do is to run you super user command with `pkexec`. That will most likely show you a graphical authentication prompt.